# Request User Location Permission In SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location, user-permissions

How do you get user location permissions in SwiftUI?

I tried asking for user location permissions after a button tap, but the dialogue box disappears after about a second. Even if you do end up clicking it in time, permission is still denied.

```
import CoreLocation
.
.
.
Button(action: {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}) {
    Image("button_image")
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Things like location manager should be in your model, not your view.

You can then invoke a function on your model to request location permission.

The problem with what you are doing now is that your `CLLocationManager` gets released as soon as the closure is done.  The permission request methods execute asynchronously so the closure ends very quickly.

When the location manager instance is released the permission dialog disappears.

A location model could look something like this:

```
class LocationModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var authorisationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    public func requestAuthorisation(always: Bool = false) {
        if always {
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}

extension LocationModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.authorisationStatus = status
    }
}
```

You would probably also want functions to start & stop location updates and an `@Published` `CLLocation` property

Comment: How do I go about structuring a model class to get the location as you described?

Comment: When should one use `extension` as you did in the example?