# Location permission dialog disappears after 1 second

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios14

I just want to ask my user for a one-time location permission. However, when I click the button that activates the permission dialog, it disappears after one second.

[This has been brought up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993353/request-user-location-permission-in-swiftui) - however I am already following this advice and storing `@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()` as a class variable in my view.

**View**

```
struct Login: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionManager: SessionManager
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        locationManager.requestPermission()
                    }){
                        Text("Verify location")
                    }
                }
```

**Model**

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    @Published var locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.unknown
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    func requestPermission(){
        print("Request permissions")
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {   switch status {
          case .restricted, .denied:
//            print(".restricted, .denied")
            locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied
             // Disable your app's location features
             break
                
          case .authorizedWhenInUse:
//            print("authorizedWhenInUse")
             // Enable your app's location features.
            locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.authorizedWhenInUse
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
             break
                
          case .authorizedAlways:
//            print(".authorizedAlways")
             // Enable or prepare your app's location features that can run any time.
            locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.authorizedAlways
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
             break
                
          case .notDetermined:
//            print(".notDetermined")
            locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.unknown
             break
       }
    }
    
    func denyPermission(){
        self.locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        self.location = location
    }

    
    enum PermissionStatus {
        case unknown
        case authorizedWhenInUse
        case authorizedAlways
        case restricted
        case denied
    }
    
    func getLocation() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        return self.location?.coordinate
    }
    
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Use `StateObject` instead and remove the `@Published` from your variables see if that is causing it. Something is likely causing your `View` to reload. maybe something from `SessionManager`

Comment: Changing to `@StateObject` fixed the problem. Thanks @lorem ipsum